# Prevent stage changes if fields on the stage are blank

Tags: case, validation-rule

I want to prevent users from changing stages for cases if they don't fill out all the fields found on that stage.  For example, on my first stage called 'Member transition started' i have a lookup field 'initiated by' followed by 3 pick list fields.

[image]

I added a validation rule that checks if the status changed, what the last value was, and if those fields are blank.  But it doesn't work and it's driving me nuts. Here is my rule:

```
AND(ISCHANGED(Status),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"Sales to Membership Transition Started"),AND(ISBLANK(TEXT(Broker__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Primary_Brand__c)),ISBLANK(Initiated_By__c)))
```

I also tried:

```
AND(ISCHANGED(Status),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"Sales to Membership Transition Started"),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Broker__c)), ISBLANK(TEXT(Primary_Brand__c)),
ISBLANK(Initiated_By__c))
```

It's really annoying and i'm stuck.  And oh yeah i also need to reproduce this on my other stages.

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer.

```
AND(ISCHANGED(Status),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"Sales to Membership Transition 
Started"),OR(ISBLANK(TEXT(Broker__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Primary_Brand__c)),ISBLANK(Initiated_By__c)))
```

I just had to switch the inside AND to an OR and it works.